# Are there any Star Trek episodes whose main theme is an infection or contagion?

Tags: star-trek

Are there any episodes, in any of all the released *Star Trek* series, whose main plot is about an infection/contagion/disease or any other medical hazard **affecting a large share of a starship crew or a planet population** (so, not about a single sick character), and about how the crew/population try to deal with it, from a medical point of view but also with its crisis management aspects?

I'm interested in episodes where the medical aspect is the main theme, or at least one of the main plots that is explored with considerable detail, not just where there is a background reference, i.e. *"We were on course to planet Random III to assist with their contagion while we encountered the energy-life-form-of-the-week"*.

Comment: Define "infection/contagion/disease"?  I can think of at least three TOS episodes that might qualify.

Comment: I'm ok to change the tags if needed. Anyway, it contents does not seem to be that different from this one https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/199013/83101 in example, or many other that ask for "episodes where...".

Comment: good grief - there's like at least one *per season* for most of the series :)

Comment: @ZeissIkon well, I mean physical disease, not related to mental health. Besides this, any kind will do, the main point is that the disease and how they deal with it should be the main plot.

Comment: As to Star Trek TNG, off the top of my head I can think of Genesis, Naked Now, and Unnatural Selection. Though honestly I think Babylon 5 did it better in the episode Confessions and Lamentations.  Way more realistic depiction of an epidemic than any of the Star Trek episodes I've personally seen.

Comment: Not sure about main theme, but there is [The Mark of Gideon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mark_of_Gideon)

Comment: I feel I should point out that there is actually an episode of TNG called “Contagion”. It’s not actually about the themes you asked about though.

Comment: 'episodes of Star Trek that deal with X' are *finite* lists and on topic. Take a look at the 'related' for the 'mental health' question; all of those are 'lists'. Just because you're tired of thinking about corvid-19 doesn't make it off topic.

Comment: still feels too broad though @Mazura - how do you define 'main theme'? Doctor's McCoy's terminal illness 'xenopolycythemia' is central to the plot in "For the World Is Hollow..." and is *said* to be contaigous or at least nominally communicable in ENT episodes - so does that count? What about Tribbles? An argument could be made for them potentially

Comment: *antibody, virus, declared a medical emergency, quarantine, treated for the Thelusian flu, health, disease, transmit, antigen, isolation, terminal*; all of those words appear in the wiki for [Unnatural Selection](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnatural_Selection_(episode)), and this being SE, no one has to define the 'main theme', you just have to vote Daishozen's answer to the top, but I haven't read the wikis for the other answers. And Tribbles: go ahead, make your argument, but I doubt it will have even half of those words describing it.

Comment: @NKCampbell - it's not too broad, it's just a lot of work to google those keywords for every ST show ever made. *This question is too hard and will require too much work* isn't a close reason, it's the antithesis of a *good* SE question.

Comment: *The question IS limited to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. It DOES NOT ask multiple distinct questions at once.* - After people are done getting their free internet points for their contributions, an adequate answer would be a CW including all of them, but no one gets points for that so no one cares, but I've seen it happen here before and I don't see why it can't happen again. The only thing standing in the way (but still not a close reason) is that it's a yes or no question as written. *Which episodes...*

Comment: @Darren: I believe *Contagion* is the first time we see Picard order tea, Earl Grey, hot. And it does not go well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most obvious is the TOS episode *The Naked Time*

> In the episode, a strange, intoxicating infection, which lowers the crew's inhibitions, spreads throughout the Enterprise. As the madness spreads, the entire ship is endangered.
>
> [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Time)

Which was referenced in the TNG episode *The Naked Now*

> In this episode, the Enterprise encounters a research ship where all personnel are found dead. The Enterprise crew quickly become infected with the same affliction, one that is similar to that suffered by the crew of James T. Kirk's USS Enterprise decades before.
>
> [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Naked_Now)

Comment: What about ["Miri"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miri_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)) or ["The Omega Glory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Omega_Glory)?  And that's just TOS...

Comment: And "City on the Edge of Forever" and "Operation: Annihilate!" (parasites are a form of disease, right?).  And this is just three seasons of TOS...

Comment: don't forget "This Side of Paradise" for TOS season 1

Comment: TOS season 2 - The Deadly Years. The Immunity Syndronme and  Trouble with Tribbles could be honorable mentions

Comment: TOS S3 - For the World is Hollow and The Cloud Minders could be honorable mentions

Comment: TOS Animated - The Terratin Incident

Answer (score 7):

The Star Trek Enterprise episodes [Affliction](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Affliction_(episode)) (4x15) and [Divergence](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Divergence_(episode)) (4x16) might fit what you're looking for. In the episode, Dr. Phlox is...persuaded to help the Klingon's deal with a virus that's threatening the entire Klingon species.

As an aside, the best example of the sci-fi medical crises story I know of is the Babylon 5 episode [Confessions and Lamentations](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Confessions_and_Lamentations)

Comment: Well, I downvoted because it's a stubby 'single example' answer to an obvious list question. I can''t speak to why others downvoted it.

Comment: same as @Valorum - one example for a question asking for a list of examples isn't a quality answer - as well as the unnecessary reference to Bablyon 5 :)

Comment: I don't think the question specified a minimum number of examples, or a minimum popularity in the specific series of Star Trek. "unnecessary reference to Bablyon 5" would be an understandable complaint if only Babylon 5 was mentioned, but it doesn't take away from the answer.

Comment: The Babylon 5 reference is clearly marked as an aside... which means it doesn't need to be included and should be deleted. Stack Exchange is not a conversation forum.

Answer (score 6):

The Deep Space Nine episode [The Quickening](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Quickening_(episode)) (4x24) deals with an illness called "the blight" on a planet in the Gamma Quadrant. The entire episode focuses on the medical situation and Dr Bashir spends a significant amount of time on the planet, trying to find a cure.

Comment: This is probably the best one of you are looking for something serious, and where the whole point is the disease impacting a culture

Comment: Also a DS9 Episode where a Bajoran virus planted in the replicator gives everyone Aphasia.

Answer (score 1):

Star Trek The Next Generation episode [Unnatural Selection](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnatural_Selection_(episode)) has a mysterious illness that destroys 1 vessel, and causes a research station to enter quarantine.

Answer (score -1):

Do biological weapons count? Then there is DS9 episode 5 [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine))
A natural Klingon disease is the main issue of Voyager episode 160 [Prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophecy_(Star_Trek:_Voyager))